# How to go about multithreading with "priority"?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi, atl

I have multiple threads processing multiple files in the background, while the program is idle.
To improve disk throughput, I use critical sections to ensure that no two threads ever use the same *disk* simultaneously.

The (pseudo-)code looks something like this:

```
void RunThread(HANDLE fileHandle)
{
    // Acquire CRITICAL_SECTION for disk
    CritSecLock diskLock(GetDiskLock(fileHandle));

    for (...)
    {
        // Do some processing on file
    }
}
```

Once the user requests a file to be processed, I need to *stop all threads* -- *except* the one which is processing the requested file. Once the file is processed, then I'd like to resume all the threads again.

Given the fact that `SuspendThread` is a bad idea, how do I go about stopping all threads except the one that is processing the relevant input?

What kind of threading objects/features would I need -- mutexes, semaphores, events, or something else? And how would I use them? (I'm hoping for compatibility with Windows XP.)

Comment: I think Condition variables would be the best way forward.

Comment: Sounds like you don't just need to pause the thread. The thread you want to run might not have the disk lock it needs. You need the thread you're "pausing" to release the disk lock, so that the thread processing the file requested can get the disk lock it needs. There isn't a built-in mechanism to do that, you need the thread itself to occasionally check some condition while it's working. One way to do that would be for each thread to process a chunk of file, release the disk lock, wait until it has permission to continue (probably on a condition variable) then regain the disk lock.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, exactly! That's the other part of the problem... I need to do something like `if (ThisThreadNeedsToSuspend()) { ReleaseDiskLock(); WaitForResumeNotice(); ReacquireDiskLock(); }` somehow, but I'm not sure what the proper way to implement it is, without causing a race condition between `ThisThreadNeedsToSuspend` and `WaitForResumeNotice`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: OK, if that's what you need I'll post an answer :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: I think I'm going to go sleep, I'll see your answer when I wake up. :-)

Comment: Note: XP does not have condition variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty here isn't priority as such, it's the fact that you want a thread to back out of a lock that it's holding, to let another thread take it. "Priority" relates to which of a set of runnable threads should be scheduled to run -- you want to make a thread runnable that isn't (because it's waiting on a lock held by another thread).

So, you want to implement (as you put it):

```
if (ThisThreadNeedsToSuspend()) { ReleaseDiskLock(); WaitForResume(); ReacquireDiskLock(); }
```

Since you're (wisely) using a scoped lock I would want to invert the logic:

```
while (file_is_not_finished) {
    WaitUntilThisThreadCanContinue();
    CritSecLock diskLock(blah);
    process_part_of_the_file();
}
ReleasePriority();

...

void WaitUntilThisThreadCanContinue() {
    MutexLock lock(thread_priority_mutex);
    while (thread_with_priority != NOTHREAD and thread_with_priority != thisthread) {
        condition_variable_wait(thread_priority_condvar);
    }
}

void GiveAThreadThePriority(threadid) {
    MutexLock lock(thread_priority_mutex);
    thread_with_priority = threadid;
    condition_variable_broadcast(thread_priority_condvar);
}

void ReleasePriority() {
    MutexLock lock(thread_priority_mutex);
    if (thread_with_priority == thisthread) {
        thread_with_priority = NOTHREAD;
        condition_variable_broadcast(thread_priority_condvar);
    }
}
```

Read up on condition variables -- all recent OSes have them, with similar basic operations. They're also in Boost and in C++11.

If it's not possible for you to write a function `process_part_of_the_file` then you can't structure it this way. Instead you need a scoped lock that can release and regain the disklock. The easiest way to do that is to make it a mutex, then you can wait on a condvar using that same mutex. You can still use the mutex/condvar pair and the `thread_with_priority` object in much the same way.

You choose the size of "part of the file" according to how responsive you need the system to be to a change in priority. If you need it to be *extremely* responsive then the scheme doesn't really work -- this is co-operative multitasking.

I'm not entirely happy with this answer, the thread with priority can be starved for a long time if there are a lot of other threads that are already waiting on the same disk lock. I'd put in more thought to avoid that. Possibly there should not be a per-disk lock, rather the whole thing should be handled under the condition variable and its associated mutex. I hope this gets you started, though.

Comment: +1 thanks for the hint on condition variables; XP doesn't have them but I'll see if I can implement something similar to them. I'll have to re-read the answer a few times to understand it better :) but so far this looks the most promising.

Comment: Ah, didn't realise that. Check what Boost provides on XP, they might have done the work for you.

Comment: I ended up figuring out an easier way that seems to work for my particular case, but I'll accept this since it seems to be a better answer for the generic case.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you go about it in a completely different fashion. If you really want only one thread for every disk (I'm not convinced this is a good idea) then you should create one thread per disk, and distribute files as you queue them for processing.

To implement priority requests for specific files I would then have a thread check a "priority slot" at several points during its normal processing (and of course in its main queue wait loop).

Comment: The problem is, none of the files has any "priority" until I get input from the user. And once I do, the "disk thread" has usually already started working on a different file... at which point I'd need to wait for it to finish before it can continue, which causes lots of latency for the user. I really need to stop everything when I get user input... so I don't see how a thread per disk would work, unless I use either fibers (hard to manage) or somehow "split up" the work of processing every file (which I'd like to avoid if possible, since it gets ugly).

Comment: As I said, I would check at multiple points during processing. Alternatively, just turn down the thread's priority and have some higher-priority thread do the user request processing.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: The "checking" part isn't the problem -- the problem is, if I *do* check and see there is something else that needs to be processed on the same (disk) thread, how do I "stop" what I'm doing? It has to continue before I can work on a different file.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Prioritization doesn't help much, because it really only works well for the CPU -- and since processing each file is both I/O bound and memory-bound (at various points during the process), it doesn't end up prioritizing very well.

Comment: +1 Sebastian's approach is correct.  @Mehrdad your problems are not hard if you follow Sebastian's suggestions.  (you are also contradicting your own specifications - you say the user wants to set a priority and then you say you can't prioritize well)  In fact, in following his suggestions, you can better ensure that you don't run into some crazy threading bugs - one mutexed job queue per thread/disk will work... ...worry about efficiency after you have working code (you can always refactor).

Comment: This is the best solution so far - queueing disk tasks to threads, though I would use two threads/queues per disk and a ManualResetObject to implement the prioritising.  Other solutions, eg. those involving checking booleans and actually exiting the thread/s before they have completed their work, are err.. 'not so optimal'.

Comment: @kfmfe04: I wasn't contradicting myself, but maybe I misunderstood Sebastian's answer -- I thought when he said "turn down the thread's priority" he was referring to `SetThreadPriority`, which only works well for CPU-bound tasks. If he was referring to the "logical" priority I was referring to then I completely misunderstood his comment.

Comment: +1, @MartinJames I'll see if I can try doing something like this... though I'm not sure I'll be able to.

Answer (score 1):

You may ask the threads to stop gracefully. Just check some variable in loop inside threads and continue or terminate work depending on its value.

Some thoughts about it:

- The setting and checking of this value should be done inside critical section.
- Because the critical section slows down the thread, the checking should be done often enough to quickly stop the thread when needed and rarely enough, such that thread won't be stalled by acquiring and releasing the critical section.

Answer (score 1):

After each worker thread processes a file, check a condition variable associated with that thread.  The condition variable could implemented simply as a bool + critical section. Or with InterlockedExchange* functions.  And to be honest, I usually just use an unprotected bool between threads to signal "need to exit" - sometimes with an event handle if the worker thread could be sleeping.

After setting the condition variable for each thread, Main thread waits for each thread to exit via WaitForSingleObject.

```
DWORD __stdcall WorkerThread(void* pThreadData)
{
    ThreadData* pData = (ThreadData*) pTheradData;

    while (pData->GetNeedToExit() == false)
    {
        ProcessNextFile();
    }
    return 0;
}

void StopWokerThread(HANDLE hThread, ThreadData* pData)
{
   pData->SetNeedToExit = true;
   WaitForSingleObject(hThread);
   CloseHandle(hThread);
}

struct ThreadData()
{
    CRITICAL_SECITON _cs;
    ThreadData()
    {
        InitializeCriticalSection(&_cs);
    }
    ~ThreadData()
    {
        DeleteCriticalSection(&_cs);
    }

    ThreadData::SetNeedToExit()
    {
        EnterCriticalSection(&_cs);
          _NeedToExit = true;
        LeaveCriticalSeciton(&_cs);
    }

    bool ThreadData::GetNeedToExit()
    {
        bool returnvalue;
        EnterCriticalSection(&_cs);
          returnvalue = _NeedToExit = true;
        LeaveCriticalSeciton(&_cs);
        return returnvalue;
    }

};
```

Comment: I'm going to need to learn more about condition variables; I haven't used them before. :) But regarding the rest of your answer -- once I've processed the user input, I need the other threads to continue what they were doing, so it's not really "need to exit" but rather "need to suspend".

Comment: Once a thread has finished executing (or if the user cancels the operation), the thread will tell the main thread about the file that was just processed -- at which point I can wake all the threads back up. The problem is, how to do it properly without `SuspendThread` and `ResumeThread`, which are dangerous.

Comment: Why are you trying to keep the threads alive when they are paused?  Just let them exit and then create new threads when it's safe to do more background work.

Comment: But then I would have to restart all over again. It's not easy for me to split up the processing of each individual file -- that's why I want to pause the threads instead.

Comment: The point I'm making is that a thread won't exit until after it's processed an individual file (a unit of work). After it processes an individual file, if it sees the main thread telling it "time to exit", it just cleans up an exits.  When it gets created again, it goes back to processing the next file.

Comment: Each thread is only ever supposed to work with 1 file though. Or are you suggesting I should change that? (And if so, how would that get rid of the delay between the time the user requests action on a file, and the time that the appropriate thread finishes working on whatever it's working on? The whole reason I had one thread per file was to be able to pause all the threads that were working on a different file than the one the user requested.)

Comment: Oh, so a thread just does an operation on a file and exits?  If that's the case, then this is even easier.  When the user "requests action", simply wait for all the existing threads to exit.  Then spin up a thread for the file the user wants.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the pool of threads and regulate their work by using the [I/O Completion port](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Normally threads from the pool would sleep awaiting for the I/O Completion port event/activity.
When you have a request the I/O Completion port releases the thread and it starts to do a job.

Answer (score 0):

OK, how about this:

Two threads per disk, for high and low priority requests, each with its own input queue.

A high-priority disk task, when initially submitted, will then issue its disk requests in parallel with any low-priority task that is running. It can reset a ManualResetEvent that the low-priority thread waits on when it can, (WaitForSingleObject) and so will get blocked if the high-prioriy thread is perfoming disk ops.  The high-priority thread should set the event after finishing a task.

This should limit the disk-thrashing to the interval, (if any), between the submission of the high-priority task and whenver the low-priority thread can wait on the MRE. Raising the CPU priority of the thread servicing the high-priority queue may assist in improving performance of the high-priority work in this interval.

Edit: by 'queue', I mean a thread-safe, blocking, producer-consumer queue, (just to be clear:).

More edit - if the issuing threads needs notification of job completion, the tasks issued to the queues could contain an 'OnCompletion' event to call with the task object as a parameter.  The event handler could, for example, signal an AutoResetEvent that the originating thread is waiting on, so providing synchronous notification.

Comment: I get the impression that a particular file can be "promoted" from low-priority to high-priority after it (and other files) are running. Basically, the background task knows that there are many files to process, and runs them in arbitrary order, but if a user becomes interested in a particular one then effort should switch to that one. So in your solution, what's the mechanism to increase a file's priority?

Comment: Oh - if that is indeed a requirement, I haven't got one :(  I had given no thought to re-prioitising tasks after submission, I assumed that the tasks would be fired off an forgotten until one or other thread fires a completion event.  Real-time priority-bodging means that some sort of list or other reference to existing tasks would have to be maintained, eg. in listBox items.  Then the actual 'priority' would have to be changed.  That would be all very messy -  the kind of gungefest that I would try vary hard to avoid.